# How to setup the Kotlin Compiler?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have installed IntelliJ Idea on MacOS and it has Kotlin support, doesn't that mean that I already have the Kotlin compiler? I know it uses the JDK as SDK but I want to be able to create a file.kt from SublimeText3 and compile it on mac terminal.

Do I need to install manually the Kotlin compiler?I have tried to call the

```
kotlinc -version command
```

and I get command not found.

Comment: Removed the repeated phrases in your and simply state one clear question about what you have installed and what you want to do. You might actually try looking at the `PATH` variable and see where the `kotlinc` executable might be installed with the installation and include that within your path.

Answer (score 9):

Also, consider installing Kotlin through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) on macOS.

```bash
> which kotlinc                                                                           

kotlinc not found
```

```bash
brew install kotlin
```

```bash
> which kotlinc                                                                           

/usr/local/bin/kotlinc
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `[IntelliJ Install Path]/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable, after that you can use `kotlinc` or `kotlin` in the command line.

Comment: I already added it to the path variable, but i get -bash: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin/kotlin: Permission denied

Comment: Why not try `bash /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin/kotlin` instead of just running `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin/kotlin`

Comment: It also gives permission denied.
i'm just calling "kotlin" command on terminal, not typing the whole path, 'cause that's why i added the path to the environment variable $PATH.

Comment: @JesúsEnriqueArriagaGómez Then you may need `chmod a+x [path to kotlin]`

Answer (score 0):

for me, in Mac OS ,the IntelliJ Idea built-in kotlin is located at:

`/Users/your user name/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin`

I append it to Evneroment Variable `Path`, so that i can use kotlin everywhere

```bash
export KT_HOME="/Users/light/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin"
PATH=$PATH:$KT_HOME
```

What's more,the old version kotlin in the path:  `[IntelliJ Install Path]/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin`